# How to move blocks to another theme region

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I have on my Drupal 7 site a MySQL data base. One of the core module [(Block)](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/block), when enabled, creates three tables (block, block_custom, block_role.) All the blocks an admin creates go into the block_custom table.

For a while now, although I can save a new block when I create it, I can no longer update the block list page (admin/structure/block.) This means I can no longer move a block to another region of my theme or change its weight. To do this, I need to go inside the block and select the new theme region although I do not have the option to change its weight there.

Similarly I cannot save or update a block for the Dashboard.

I have tried to find existing blocks that could be the cause of this. One by one, out of some 100 blocks I was able to get the block page to save after deleting 22 blocks.

However, since I need those deleted block, I went ahead and recreated them thinking the old blocks were somehow corrupt and needed fresh replacements. I expected the new blocks to be appended to the end of the table.

I do not know if this has some relevance but some of the new blocks were indeed appended (no sorting) while others went to fill in the empty spaces left by the deleted blocks (the block IDs (bid) did not follow in sequence.)

Be that as it may, after having re-created the 22 blocks, I am back to square one and I still can't move blocks or update the block list page!

Can anyone tell me what's going on and what I should do to fix this? I am not a data base expert and any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work by making a dump of the table data (not the structure) then deleting the data inside the table and then re-importing the data into the table. Didn't even optimize the table before this last operation.

Although I am not sure what this did, it was an easy procedure. Not that obvious to figure out though. Also, it cleared a couple of other issues with Organic Groups that were giving me a WSD with the message: "The website has encountered an unexpected error, please try again later"

Looks like the website is running seamlessly now.

:)